# How to use smooth filter in image in iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, filter

I am creating am app of image processing in which i am using some filter on image but i am unable to use smooth filter in image in iphone sdk. So please help me how can implement the smooth functionality on image in iOS app.

original image :
[image] after smooth :
[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple `Gaussian Blur` to apply on the image.

Try `CIFilters` from iOS, find list of filter [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html).

```
-(UIImage *)smoothImage:(UIImage *)input{

    CIContext *context_ = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    UIImage *defaultImage_=input;

    CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[defaultImage_ CGImage]];

    //Apply CIBloom that makes soft edges and adds glow to image
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBloom"];
    [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:6.0] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
    CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

    CGImageRef cgImage = [context_ createCGImage:result fromRect:[result extent]];
    UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);

    return resultImage;

}
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: this code not generate good quality smooth image. please provide another way to smooth image.

Comment: I have not tested the code, you can always try with different values, and do check other filters, of it suits.